# I am not able to install head versioned apps for gmail addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, gmail-addons

I have developed an add-on for Gmail. I added the id of the head version in Gmail -> settings -> addon and developed the app. But now all my head version deployed apps removed from my Gmail account. when I try to add them it's not showing any error and not getting the app also. if I create a new deployment and install then I am getting that app but not able to install the head version app. can someone help me with this?

Recently my app verification in from the OAuth consent screen and my domain verification for approved by google. is it something related to this?

Comment: Can you share the code of your add-on or an example?

Comment: I cannot share the current project code as it is having our company-related data. But I can tell the share demo app which I tried. Here is the google sample expense it app https://github.com/googlecodelabs/gmail-add-ons/tree/master/Full-application. I installed it in the beginning and it is working but not it is not working having the same problem. if I create new project with the same code in the above link that is working. It means for all my existing apps I am not able to install the head version. Can you try to find something based on this information?